# How to modify lib files downloaded from maven via gradle, at compile time?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, compilation

I have a library added as dependency.

I'd like to modify (delete) some of the files as soon as they are downloaded from the Maven repository, BEFORE the compilation itself.

Is there a way to add a Gradle task to make those changes between the lib download and the compilation?

Comment: What files are you deleting? Give an example?

Comment: Inside the apk there is a folder (with the library package structure) with a list of files where are stored some informations it uses. I need to keep only a few of those files and delete the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following. Create your own local maven repository, which is a great idea for your own dependencies within your own application BTW and worth doing in its own right. Have you are repository pass through to maven central or whatever.

Construct your *own* release of this library (with your changes/deletions) within your own maven repository. Now simply point your gradle dependency at this new repository and your done.

If you ever need to fix an open source library fast (I do) just fork it and create a new library release in your repository. So you can solve several issues and not jump through hoops with fancy gradle scripting.

So in summation if you have a dependency issue fix it in the repository if possible rather than the gradle script IMHO.